# Completion Suggester - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an issue about the completion suggester.

I have a string dataset with data like :
"paris", "london", "france", "a city in France", "nothing at all", ...

I would like search into my data with for example this input : "an" and have this results : "fr**an**ce", "**a** city in Fr**an**ce", "**n**othing **a**t **a**ll"

is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve something similar to what you want by using partial matching with n-grams. In order to do it every word in your dataset should be split into so called n-grams - moving windows of word where n is a length of this window. To not repeat Elasticsearch docs here is the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html).
Everything comes with a price. Here the price is an increased size of the index.